# Identify Vintage Power Cord for Sears Electric Tray

Tags: power, ac, identification, input, vintage

I found this vintage Sears electric warming tray but it's missing a power cord. I tried a 2 prong figure 8 cord but the holes were too close together or too small to fit. Here are pictures of the tray, power requirements on the label, etc. *UPDATE* Dimensions are 7/8 by 1/2 in with 5/16 in between the two prongs. It's not a perfect rectangle as the edges are rounded. Hope this helps!
[image]

Comment: Looks like the same type used for hair driers and curling irons

Comment: Haven't seen one of those cords in years.  You could maybe get someone to solder a new cord to the pins for you, then pot the opening in epoxy.  But maybe the best solution would be to get a new warming tray.

Comment: Get some dimensions, I’m sure someone here is well versed in historical power cord standards.

Comment: Open it and replace with a new socket and matching new cord.

Comment: I'm curious to know if the metal on those two external holes and/or the metal lining the rectangular cavity are electrically connected to one of the two pins.  If so, you might have to be careful of the polarity of whatever cord or retrofit you use, as you would rather have those points be connected to neutral instead of hot when plugged in.

Comment: That looks like an old school TV "cheater cord" might work. They have pin spacing of about 7.2-7.4 mm. https://www.surplussales.com/Electrical/ElecCords-1.html

Comment: They were very common about 40 or so years ago. Look at replacement cords for antiques. I purchased a few about 10 years ago for some test equipment. I have seen them once or twice since but not to often. Check some of the online places such as ebay etc that will sell antique electronics.